# Discrepancy in Maxwell's extended Hamiltonian

Tags: gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, classical-field-theory

In the 4D Maxwell's extended Hamiltonian action, I obtain the same expression of [Fuentealba, Henneaux and Troessaert](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.05989.pdf) (see the picture), up to the term "$\partial^i\pi^0 A_i$", although my procedure is in agreement with [this PSE thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314345/total-vs-extended-action-on-constrained-dynamics). How can I obtain it?

[image]

Here, $\mathcal{G}=-\partial_i\pi^i$ is Gauss' law.

For completeness, explicit details can be found below.

**My procedure**

I am interested in flat space, so $\sqrt{g}=1$.

We start by space-time splitting the squared of the field strength in the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}=-(1/4) F^2$,
\begin{align}
 F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=F_{0i}F^{0i}+F_{ij}F^{ij}+F_{i0}F^{i0}=2F_{0i}F^{0i}+F_{ij}F^{ij}\,.
\end{align}
Then the action reads
\begin{align}
 I=-\frac{1}{4}\int d^4x\,\left(2F_{0i}F^{0i}+F_{ij}F^{ij}\right)\,.
\end{align}
We now proceed to compute the Legendre transformation of the Lagrangian. The canonical momentum density is determined as the derivative of the Lagrangian density with respect to the temporal derivative of the gauge field $A_\mu$, from where we obtain
\begin{align}
 \pi^0\approx 0\,,\quad \pi^i=-F^{0i}\,.
\end{align}
Here $\approx$ denotes a relation that holds in the naive phase space (without imposition of constraints).

Observe that $\pi^i=-F^{0i}=-\left(\partial^0 A^i-\partial^i A^0\right)=\dot{A}^i+\partial^i A^0=-E^i$. Therefore, $\pi^0$ corresponds to a \textit{primary constraint}, and secondly, $\pi^i$ allows us to express the generalized velocity as $\partial^0 A^i=-\pi^i+\partial^i A^0$. Then, the Legendre transformation is given by
\begin{align}
 \begin{split}
  H=\int d^3x\,\left(\pi^\mu\dot{A}_\mu-\mathcal{L}\right)=\int d^3x\,\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi_i\pi^i+\frac{1}{4}F_{ij}F^{ij}+\pi^i\partial_i A_0\right)\,.
 \end{split}
\end{align}
Following Dirac's notation, and integrating the last term by parts, we arrive to what is known as the canonical Hamiltonian density
\begin{align}
  \mathcal{H}_c=\frac{1}{2}\pi_i\pi^i+\frac{1}{4}F_{ij}F^{ij}-A_0\partial_i\pi^i\,.
\end{align}
Therefore, we formulate the so-called primary Hamiltonian (the canonical Hamiltonian $+$ primary constraints)
\begin{align}
 H_p\left[A_0,A_i,\pi^0,\pi^i\right]=\int d^3x\,\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi_i\pi^i+\frac{1}{4}F_{ij}F^{ij}-A_0\partial_i\pi^i+\lambda_1\pi^0\right)\,.
\end{align}
It can be seen that $A_0$ is a Lagrange multiplier, while the constraint $\partial_i\pi^i$ corresponds to Gauss's law.

Next, we examine the consistency of the primary constraint $\pi^0$ and investigate whether it generates a secondary constraint. For this purpose, we define the Poisson bracket as
\begin{align}
 \left\{A_\mu(x),\pi^\nu(x')\right\}=\delta_\mu^\nu\delta^{(3)}(x-x')\,.
\end{align}
The temporal evolution of the primary constraint,
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: Phi1 Maxwell}
 \Phi_1=\pi^0\,,
\end{align}
yields
\begin{align}
 \begin{split}
  \dot{\Phi}_1=\left\{\pi^0(x),H_p\right\}=-\int d^3x'\,\left\{\pi^0(x),A_0(x')\right\}\partial'_i\pi^i(x')&=-\int d^3x\,\delta^{(3)}(x-x')\partial'_i\pi^i(x')\\
  &=-\partial_i\pi^i\approx 0\,.
 \end{split}
\end{align}
Therefore, the temporal evolution of the primary constraint $\pi^0$ generates a secondary constraint, which corresponds to Gauss's law,
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: Phi2 Maxwell}
 \Phi_2=-\partial_i\pi^i\,.
\end{align}
Continuing with Dirac's algorithm, the evolution of this constraint is
\begin{align}
 \begin{split}
  \dot{\Phi}_2=\left\{\partial_i\pi^i(x),H_p\right\}&=-\frac{1}{4}\partial_i\int d^3x'\,\left\{\pi^i(x),\partial'_k A_l(x')-\partial_l A_k(x')\right\}F^{kl}(x')\\
  &=\frac{1}{4}\partial_i\int d^3x'\,\left(\delta^i_l\partial_k'-\delta^i_k\partial_l'\right)\delta^{(3)}(x-x')F^{kl}(x')\,.
 \end{split}
\end{align}
Integrating by parts, we find
\begin{align}
 \dot{\Phi}_2=-\frac{1}{4}\partial_i\int d^3x\,\delta^{(3)}(x-x')\left(\delta^i_l\partial_k'-\delta^i_k\partial_l'\right)F^{kl}(x')=-\frac{1}{4}\left(\partial_l\partial_k-\partial_k\partial_l\right)F^{kl}=0\,.
\end{align}
Consequently, we conclude that no new constraints are generated, thus $\Phi_{1,2}$ are the only ones.

Subsequently, the total Hamiltonian density is expressed as
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{H}_T=\mathcal{H}_c+\tilde{\epsilon}\Phi^1+\tilde{\mu}\Phi^2\,, 
\end{align}
where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are undetermined Lagrange multipliers. Thus, the total Hamiltonian action can be written as
\begin{align}
 I_H=\int dt\int d^3x\,\left(\pi^0\dot{A}_0+\pi^i\dot{A}_i-\mathcal{H}_T\right)\,.
\end{align}
We investigate now whether $\Phi_1$ or $\Phi_2$ are first or second-class constraints. The answer is direct, since $\left\{\Phi_1,\Phi_2\right\}\approx 0$. Therefore, $\Phi_{1,2}$ are first-class constraints and the extended Hamiltonian reads
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_E=\mathcal{H}_T+\psi\Phi_1+\lambda\Phi_2\,.
\end{align}
However, observe that the term $\partial^i\pi^0 A_i$ did not appear.

Comment: Why would it appear here? It comes from the constraint terms, some of which are in $H_T$, so try to replace $H_T$ with its expression in terms of $\pi^i,A_0,\pi^0$ -that's where another term involving $\pi^0$ can come from.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you're trying to do - is to recover the expression for the extended Hamiltonian action from the quoted work, where the term $\partial^i\pi^0 A_i$ appears?

Comment: If so, it seems to me maybe it can come from the term $\lambda_1 \pi^0$, somehow connecting $\lambda_1$ to $\partial_i A^i$.

Comment: @JánLalinský, "Maybe I don't get what you're trying to do - is to recover the expression for the extended Hamiltonian action from the quoted work, where the term $\partial^i\pi^0 A_i$ appears?". Yep.